# delay websocket updates and show the message later on?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, vue.js

I have an app where basically players challenge each other. At some point their challenge completes and I need to provide them (both of them - there are two players) with an update message, like 'Hey, you won and got 100500 points'. And vice versa - "Hey You looose"

I use websockets and `pusher` api to tackle the live updates, this works perfectly when player is "online". But what if they are not? The way to go for me looks like I can still handle the event with pusher and instead just displaying the message, I can store it to db to table `challenge_notifications` with fields `messages` and `seen = 0`. it's ok, but what would be the best way then to show this to the player when he comes online next time? I don't want to have ajax request on every page load checking to see if there are any unseen notifications for the user.

I probably somehow need to fetch all pending notifications only once, when they get online?

I use `Laravel 5` for my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a recent post on the Pusher blog about how to detect if a user is online or not using the Pusher HTTP API: [Enabling Smart Notifications with Pusher and SendGrid](https://blog.pusher.com/smart-notifications-with-pusher-and-sendgrid/).

The example uses SendGrid, but you could instead store the update to a database, send them a Push Notification, an SMS etc.

> what would be the best way then to show this to the player when he comes online next time?

I guess there are two forms of "coming online":

1. The user is no longer on the site and has to navigate to the site. In that case as the page loads you can query the DB and serve them up any missed notifications directly (this would seem the easiest solution). Or, if it fits your app architecture, make a single AJAX request when the page loads to get any missed notifications.
2. If the user has gone offline due to them being mobile or having a bad network connection. In that case you can bind to the `connected` event using `pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {});` and then make a query to see if they've missed any notifications.

In summary: it would seem that querying the DB for any missed notifications upon normal page render (on the server) would be the simplest solution and wouldn't required much resource usage. But there are alternative mechanisms of delivering a notifications (email, SMS) if they're not online.